# HP 2600 Printer not working 18.4

Tags: apt, software-center

aww boy did i screw something up i've uninstalled my printer and now i cant get it back. this is what i did so far with any progresss

```
rick@rick-System-Product-Name:~$ gksudo hp-setup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: libapt-pkg.so.6.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: libapt-pkg.so.6.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: libapt-pkg.so.6.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Also please add output of `dpkg -S libapt-pkg.so.6.0` to the question.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04.01

Comment: and on the dpkg j get   this     dpkg -S libapt-pkg.so.6.0
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *libapt-pkg.so.6.0*

Comment: To be sure, do you have any errors while running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: yes i do get errors

Comment: For me it looks like you have installed wrong package version manually. Normally installed 18.04 LTS system has [`libapt-pkg.so.5.0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libapt-pkg.so.) Please share the output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` and `apt-cache policy   libapt-pkg5.0` command in question or by using pastebin.

Comment: ok this is greip -r ^drn

Comment: lt wont let me put  all  the stuff in  here  is the apt  cache policy one  ame:~$ apt-cache policy libapt-pkg5.0
libapt-pkg5.0:
  Installed: 1.6.12
  Candidate: 1.6.12
  Version table:
 *** 1.6.12 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status